# Material UI select multiple component using an object in the value property, adds duplicate entry

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, material-ui, multi-select

I have a multi select that i pass an object into the value property with the structure:

[image]

The select component looks like this:

```
<Select
            multiple
            value={entities}
            onChange={handleChange}
            input={<Input />}
            renderValue={(selected) => (
              <div className={classes.chips}>
                {selected.map((value) => (
                  <Chip
                    key={value.entityId}
                    label={value.entityName}
                    className={classes.chip}
                  />
                ))}
              </div>
            )}
          >
            {props.entityList.map((item, index) => (
              <MenuItem key={item.entityId} value={item}>
                {item.entityName}
              </MenuItem>
            ))}
          </Select>
```

when the select pops up it shows the entity name correct but does not show it as selected in the dropdown.

If i select this item in the drop down it adds another entry which has the same id and same name rather than removing the item that is already there, this newly added duplicate can be removed and is highlighted when selected so the functionality works somewhat.

I am storing `entities` in the state like so that comes in from a parent component:

[image]

Solution:

I have made sure that the same object is being used across the select, the initial object was not the same as the objects that where being assigned in the on Change function. this fixed my problem.

```
const [entities, setEntity] = React.useState(
props.entityList.filter((e) =>
  props.assignedEntities.some((ae) => e.entityId === ae.entityId)
)
```

);

Comment: When using objects as the values for a `Select`, they will only be considered matching if they are the [exact same object](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.10.2/packages/material-ui/src/Select/SelectInput.js#L16). Two different objects that happen to have the same content will not be considered matching.

Comment: @RyanCogswell This makes sense, so are you saying here my props.assignedEntities is not match even.target.value. Can you recommend a solution.

Comment: Without seeing a full reproduction of your problem (particularly how `props.entityList` and `props.assignedEntities` are managed), it is difficult to recommend a solution. My suspicion is that `props.assignedEntities` has separate copies of the objects in `props.entityList` rather than reusing the exact same objects. I would recommend initializing your `entities` state using `props.entityList.filter(...)` where you filter by the assigned entity ids such that `entities` is guaranteed to reuse objects from `props.entityList`.

Comment: @RyanCogswell Awesome i understand this concept now and will defo help me going forward, i have updated my answer to include the fix, Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

I had exact problem and I solved it in the following way.

In my example I'm using role to user assignment:

Here is my **role** object:

```
Role
-----
id,
name,
access,
createdUtc
```

My component receives these props:

```
allRoles
user // that has user.roles
```

Here I extract only ids of the roles:

```
 const [selectedRoleIds, setSelectedRoleIds] = useState([]);

 useEffect(() => {
    if(user) {
      setSelectedRoleIds(user.roles.map(i => i.id));
    }

 }, [user]);
```

My multi select component:

```
<Select
    multiple
    value={selectedRoleIds}
    onChange={handleRoleChange}
    input={<OutlinedInput id="select-multiple-chip" label="Chip" />}
    renderValue={(selected) => (
    <Box sx={{ display: 'flex', flexWrap: 'wrap', gap: 0.5 }}>
        {selected.map((roleId) => (
        <Chip key={roleId} label={allRoles?.find(e => e.id === roleId).name} />
        ))}
    </Box>
    )}
    MenuProps={MenuProps}
>
    {roles.map((role) => (
    <MenuItem key={role.id} value={role.id}>
        <Checkbox checked={selectedRoleIds.includes(role.id)} />
        <ListItemText primary={role.name} />
    </MenuItem>
    ))}                      
</Select>
```

Handling role change is easy as:

```
  const handleRoleChange = (event) => {
    const {value} = event.target;
    setSelectedRoleIds(value);

  };
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My version for this:

```
    import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Select, MenuItem, InputLabel, FormControl } from '@material-ui/core';

interface Option {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}

const options: Option[] = [
  { id: 1, name: 'Option 1' },
  { id: 2, name: 'Option 2' },
  { id: 3, name: 'Option 3' },
];

const MultipleSelect: React.FC = () => {
  const [selectedOptions, setSelectedOptions] = useState<Option[]>([]);

  const handleChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<{ value: unknown }>) => {
    const values = event.target.value as number[];
    const selected = values.map(value => options.find(option => option.id === value)!);
    setSelectedOptions(selected);
  };

  return (
    <FormControl fullWidth>
      <InputLabel id="multiple-select-label">Select</InputLabel>
      <Select
        labelId="multiple-select-label"
        id="multiple-select"
        multiple
        value={selectedOptions.map(option => option.id)}
        onChange={handleChange}
        renderValue={(selected) => (
        <Box sx={{ display: "flex", flexWrap: "wrap", gap: 0.5 }}>
          {selected.map((roleId) => (
            <Chip key={roleId} label={options.find((o) => o.id === roleId)!.name} />
          ))}
        </Box>
      )}
      >
        {options.map(option => (
          <MenuItem key={option.id} value={option.id}>
            {option.name}
          </MenuItem>
        ))}
      </Select>
    </FormControl>
  );
};

export default MultipleSelect;
```